# Randomising two teams Php Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, random

I am constructing a game where users join into a game lobby and then get split into two teams, and then answer questions.
But I have a problem, everything except the team randomiser is done.
I want the users to be assigned to a team when a button is pressed, which is not a problem, I can do this.

The problem is making the teams.
As it is now I'm getting and displaying the current users by this line of code

```
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo utf8_encode("<div><br>". $row["name"]. " <b>| Lag : </b><span>" . $row["team"] . "</span><br></div>"); // för namn osv 
            mysqli_close($link);
        }
    }
}
echo "";
```

I want all users to randomly be assigned to two large teams equally, therefore I can not use a simple randomiser giving the user 50/50 chance to be on one or the other team because there is a chance of making the teams extremely unequal.

When the user has been assigned to a team, the script will run a query updating a column called "team" for each user and then the game will start.

How can I make it so that when a button is pressed, the code takes the users and puts all the users into two different teams?
Is this done with arrays, or what? I'm clueless!

It is important that the teams are as equal as possible.

What should I do?
I have seen things with javascript, but that doesn't work here.

---

**clarifications.**

There are no max players, there are **two** teams. I will run a query assigning the users to a team in the database.

If I have missed something, or if more information is needed, just tell me!

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Hint: To put people on two teams, assign a random "order" number to each user, then split them out as odd/even or first half/second half in the resulting sequence.

Comment: You could just store all users in an array, shuffle the array and then do an array_chunk that's half the total of users. Then you'll have two arrays with random users.

Comment: I have looked into that, but how do i work with the array after? Im left with an array but i got no clue on how to use it. How can i update the column ??

Comment: @Jonas if I got anything incorrect in my edit with regards to clarifying your post, do fix it, please.

Comment: @Tiffany It looks good! thanks :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've got the list players in the result set use the shuffle() function to shuffle them up, then assign the 1st half of the players to team 1 and the other half to team 2

Below assumes that there will be two teams with an even number of players:

```
<?php

$players = array("Player 1","Player 2","Player 3","Player 4","Player 5","Player 6","Player 7","Player 8");

//Players list before shuffling
var_dump($players);
shuffle($players);

//Players list after shuffling
var_dump($players);

// Get number of players per team
$player_count = count($players);
$players_per_team = $player_count/2;

$teams = array_chunk($players,$players_per_team);

$team_1 = $teams[0];
$team_2 = $teams[1];

echo 'Team 1';
var_dump($team_1);

echo 'Team 2';
var_dump($team_2);
```

Comment: Sounds like it could work! Could you please provide me with some sort of example on what this could look like, thanks!